# Why am I getting KafkaJSLockTimeout error with Node.js Kafka project and how to resolve it?

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka, timeout

How can I resolve the `KafkaJSLockTimeout: Timeout while acquiring lock` error when connecting to a Kafka broker?

I'm running a Node.js Project that uses React.jsx, Prisma and PostGres.
I'm encountering the following error while trying to connect to a Kafka broker using KafkaJS:

`"KafkaJSLockTimeout: Timeout while acquiring lock (XX waiting locks): 'connect to broker [broker_address]'.`

```
{"level":"INFO","timestamp":"2023-06-01T13:38:37.214Z","logger":"kafkajs","message":"[Consumer] Starting","groupId":"my-app"}
{"level":"ERROR","timestamp":"2023-06-01T13:38:38.231Z","logger":"kafkajs","message":"[Connection] Connection timeout","broker":"DESKTOP-L1MH9PU.:9092","clientId":"my-app"}
{"level":"ERROR","timestamp":"2023-06-01T13:38:38.234Z","logger":"kafkajs","message":"[Consumer] Crash: KafkaJSConnectionError: Connection timeout","groupId":"my-app","stack":"KafkaJSConnectionError: Connection timeout\n    at Timeout.onTimeout [as _onTimeout] (C:\\Users\\stefa\\OneDrive\\Documentos\\Faculdade\\Modulo 4\\app\\backend\\node_modules\\kafkajs\\src\\network\\connection.js:223:23)\}
```

Here are the related files:

producer.js

```
const { Kafka, Partitioners } = require('kafkajs');

const clientId = 'my-app';
const brokers = ['localhost:9092'];
const topic = 'message-log';

const kafka = new Kafka({ clientId, brokers });
const producer = kafka.producer({ createPartitioner: Partitioners.LegacyPartitioner });

const produce = async () => {
  await producer.connect();
  let i = 0;

  setInterval(async () => {
    try {
      const result = await producer.send({
        topic,
        messages: [
          {
            key: String(i),
            value: 'esta é a mensagem ' + i,
          },
        ],
      });

      // Log the result to see more details about the successful message send
      console.log('Message sent successfully:', result);
      console.log('writes:', i);
      i++;
    } catch (err) {
      console.error('não foi possível escrever a mensagem', err);

      // If there's an error in sending the message, log more details about the error
      if (err.message) {
        console.error('Error message:', err.message);
      }
      if (err.stack) {
        console.error('Stack trace:', err.stack);
      }
    }
  }, 1000);
};

module.exports = produce;
```

Consumer.js

```
// a instância kafka e as variáveis de configuração são as mesmas de antes
const { Kafka } = require("kafkajs")
const clientId = "my-app"
const brokers = ["localhost:9092"]
const topic = "message-log"

const kafka = new Kafka({ clientId, brokers })
const consumer = kafka.consumer({ groupId: clientId })

const consume = async () => {
    // primeiro, esperamos que o cliente se conecte e se inscreva no tópico fornecido
    await consumer.connect()
    await consumer.subscribe({ topic })
    await consumer.run({
        // esta função é chamada toda vez que o consumidor recebe uma nova mensagem
        eachMessage: ({ message }) => {
            // aqui, apenas registramos a mensagem na saída padrão
            console.log(`mensagem recebida: ${message.value}`)
        },
    })
}

module.exports = consume
```

app.js

```
const express = require('express')
require('express-async-errors')
require('dotenv').config()
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const cors = require('cors')
const log4js = require('log4js');
const swaggerJsDoc = require('swagger-jsdoc');
const swaggerUi = require('swagger-ui-express');
const produce = require("./producer")
const consume = require("./consumer")

// Swagger options
const swaggerOptions = {
  swaggerDefinition: {
    info: {
      title: 'API',
      description: 'API Information',
      contact: {
        name: 'Developer Name'
      },
      servers: ['http://localhost:3001']
    }
  },
  apis: ['./routes/*.js']
};

const swaggerDocs = swaggerJsDoc(swaggerOptions);

//Configurando Log de Usuários
log4js.configure({
    appenders: {
      multi: {
        type: "multiFile",
        base: "logs/",
        property: "categoryName",
        extension: ".log",
      },
    },
    categories: {
      default: { appenders: ["multi"], level: "debug" },
    },
});

const app = express()
app.use(cors())

app.use(express.json()) //Irá suportar JSON
app.use(
    bodyParser.urlencoded({
        // Irá suportar urlenconded
        extended: true,
    })
)

app.use('/api-docs', swaggerUi.serve, swaggerUi.setup(swaggerDocs));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Pong!')
})

// Rotas
const userRouter = require('./routes/user')
const ContentRouter = require('./routes/content');
const projectRouter = require('./routes/project');

app.use('/v1/content', ContentRouter);
app.use('/v1/user', userRouter)
app.use('/v1/project', projectRouter)

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.status(404).send({ error: 'Not found', status: 404, url: req.url })
})


// chame a função `produce` e registre um erro se ocorrer
produce().catch((err) => {
    console.error("erro no produtor: ", err)
})

// inicie o consumidor e registre quaisquer erros
consume().catch((err) => {
    console.error("erro no consumidor: ", err)
})

// O resto do seu código segue aqui


const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Servidor rodando na porta http://localhost:${PORT}`)
})
```

I've started the zookeeper enviroment with  `bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties` then started the kafka server with `bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/server.properties`, and both are working.
But when i try to run the projects backend with `node app.js` the server runs in the desired port. However the console starts printing these logs:

```
{"level":"INFO","timestamp":"2023-06-01T13:38:37.214Z","logger":"kafkajs","message":"[Consumer] Starting","groupId":"my-app"}
{"level":"ERROR","timestamp":"2023-06-01T13:38:38.231Z","logger":"kafkajs","message":"[Connection] Connection timeout","broker":"DESKTOP-L1MH9PU.:9092","clientId":"my-app"}
{"level":"ERROR","timestamp":"2023-06-01T13:38:38.234Z","logger":"kafkajs","message":"[Consumer] Crash: KafkaJSConnectionError: Connection timeout","groupId":"my-app","stack":"KafkaJSConnectionError: Connection timeout\n    at Timeout.onTimeout [as _onTimeout] (C:\\Users\\stefa\\OneDrive\\Documentos\\Faculdade\\Modulo 4\\app\\backend\\node_modules\\kafkajs\\src\\network\\connection.js:223:23)\}
```